# mutate() in (d)plyr does not create new column when sourced

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I am using the package dplyr with R (same problem applies to plyr, too). When I call `source("dply_problem.R")` to the following code

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame("A" = 1:6,
                 "B" = 7:12)
mutate(df, C = A + B)
```

the column "C" does not get added to `df`. However, when I call `mutate(df, C = A + B)` from the shell, the column "C" does get created. Could you give me a hint why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try assigning the output of `mutate` to "df"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You haven't assigned the output to anything. Try:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame("A" = 1:6,
                 "B" = 7:12)
df <- mutate(df, C = A + B)

df
```

Comment: @paljenczy if this answer suits your needs you may want to consider marking the checkmark next to it to indicate to future searchers that this answer most correctly suited the question.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using pipe operator. dplyr imports this operator from another package (magrittr)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("A" = 1:6,
                 "B" = 7:12)
df1<- df %>% mutate(C = A + B)
```